# How can I create a search bar with a button on it "copy" when someone writes something and clicks on copy it automatically copies it?

Tags: html, copy, searchbar

How can I create a search bar with a "copy"  button when someone writes something and clicks on "copy" it automatically copies it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a button with onclick = myFunction();

And the function should look smth like that:

```
function myFunction() {
   /* Get the text field */
   var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

   /* Select the text field */
   copyText.select();

   /* Copy the text inside the text field */
   document.execCommand("copy");

}
```

more information: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

Comment: @MehdiBourechka Happy to help you. Btw you can now mark your question as answered by clicking the check box next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Martin for you quick answer !

I had just been trying this tuto : https://www.it-cooking.com/technology/web/cms/wordpress/copy-text-code-button-wordpress/#comment-151

By installing 3 plug-in, but I couldn't make it work. (I will try again)

I will try also your proposition and give you a feedback.

Thanks a lot